# Capture touch events on 3D model in LibGDX

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

```
public static class GameObject extends ModelInstance {
    public final Vector3 center = new Vector3();
    public final Vector3 dimensions = new Vector3();
    public final float radius;

    private final static BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();

    public GameObject (Model model, String rootNode, boolean mergeTransform)
    {
        super(model, rootNode, mergeTransform);
        calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
        bounds.getCenter(center);
        bounds.getDimensions(dimensions);
        radius = dimensions.len() / 2f;
    }
}


@Override
public void create()
{
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(150,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                                   Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 0f);
    camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0);
    camera.near = 0f;
    camera.far = 100f;
    camera.update();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();

    G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
    model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("map.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
    modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
    GameObject object = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < modelInstance.nodes.size; i++)
    {
        object = new GameObject(model, modelInstance.nodes.get(i).id, true);
        countries.add(object);
        System.out.println(object.center);
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
{
    countryIsTouched(screenX, screenY);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void countryIsTouched(int screenX, int screenY)
{
    Ray ray = camera.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);
    modelInstance.transform.getTranslation(position);
    float distance = -1;
    int result = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < countries.size; ++i)
    {
        final GameObject instance = countries.get(i);
        instance.transform.getTranslation(position);
        position.add(instance.center);
        final float len = ray.direction.dot(position.x-ray.origin.x, position.y-ray.origin.y, position.z-ray.origin.z);
        if (len < 0f)
            continue;
        float dist2 = position.dst2(ray.origin.x+ray.direction.x*len, ray.origin.y+ray.direction.y*len, ray.origin.z+ray.direction.z*len);
        if (distance >= 0f && dist2 > distance) 
            continue;
        if (dist2 <= instance.radius * instance.radius) {
            result = i;
            distance = dist2;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help or guidance!
Does the camera properties have any impact on this since the ray picking never detect any touch?

Comment: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/interacting-with-3d-objects/ also, make sure to understand the difference between a mesh, meshpart, node, model and modelinstance.

Comment: @Xoppa: Thanks for your reply, I have taken a look at the tutorials you provided. But I am unable to detect when any of the objects is touched. The countryIsTouhed method does not fire on any of the objects I click on the screen. Is there anything specific that I do completely wrong here?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the code with that camera setup actually runs and shows something, let alone that ray picking would work. Perhaps start at the beginning at https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/.

Comment: @Xoppa: Thanks again. I tried it with the example you have written a tutorial on and it works when I use the exact same model. However, with my model it works if I change  if (dist2 <= instance.radius * instance.radius) to if (dist2 >= instance.radius * instance.radius). I guess this could be due to something about that I may or may not flip coordinates?